# How to exclude words using grep?

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

Instead of me chaining these like 10 times

```
cat /var/log/nginx/access.log | grep -v download | grep -v danger | grep -v "/visitor/return" | grep -v welcome | grep -v "GET / HTTP" | grep -v "/baby/" | grep -v "/paste/" | awk '{ print $1, $4, $7 }' >> access.$(date "+%Y-%m-%d").txt
```

Is there a way to combine them into a list or an array for a bit cleaner to read ?

---

## I tried

```
grep -wv 'download|danger|/visitor/return|welcome|GET / HTTP|/baby/|/paste/' | awk '{ print $1, $4, $7 }' >> access.$(date "+%Y-%m-%d").txt
```

no luck, even with `-v` **only**

---

I thinking I'm setting here for the best

```
cat /var/log/nginx/access.log | grep -v -e "download" -e "danger" -e "/visitor/return" -e "welcome" -e "GET / HTTP" -e "/baby/" -e "/paste/" | awk '{ print $1, $4, $7 }' >> access.$(date "+%Y-%m-%d").txt
```

If you guys know a better one, I would like to learn from you. !

Answer (score 0):

You may use the -Ev flag:

```
grep -Ev 'house|garden' file.txt
```

will show all lines that do **not** the words "house" or "garden".

1. -E: Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression
2. -v: Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.

An alternative would be the -v flag with egrep:

```
egrep -v '(house|garden)' file.txt
```